# Prevent the same window to take share the session

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me to prevent sharing the same session
If the two computers open the same page as example "registration Form "
and the two insert data in the same time
I created session to store some data in code behind before insertion

how I could prevent the two's to share the same session 
I mean to prevent make overlap in the two insertion

Comment: Can you use the viewstate instead of the session, that way it would be instance specific not session specific?

Comment: you mean that way affect only on my current page

Comment: you mean that this way will affect only on my current page ??.. If the two computers open the same page on the same time for doing insert .. the view state in every page is different ??  right ??

Comment: What you describe can't happen. Two visitors from two different computers will always get two different sessions, even if logging with same credentials.

Comment: i deleted my previous answer because i missread the post i thought you wanted to prevent 2 browser windows to share the same session.
Do you work with asp.net or asp-classic ? you selected both tags but these are 2 different things, asp-classic is the old asp before .net
Also as already mentionned 2 computers can't share the same session, it seems more like a shared ressource lock problem, can you explain more in detail what is happening exactly ? some code sample would help too